# Purpose of empty HTML comment in a div marked clearfix

Tags: html, css, shim

What is the purpose of an empty comment in a clearfix div?  I assume this is for some sort of older browser shim; not sure why you would want to go around putting empty comments everywhere though. Seems just one or two CSS rules would be a heck of a lot easier to maintain.

[image: empty html comment]

Answer (score 1):

If the website has two divs next to eachother using display: inline-block, the whitespace between those divs will add annoying space in the layout. To combat this, developers use html comments that start right after the closing tag of the left div, and end right before the opening tag of the right div, with no space between the tags.

Answer (score 1):

CSS can (or could at the time) only format elements and pseudo-elements.  An element *after* the [float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) is needed for clearing the float, i.e. for [returning to the normal document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear).

The `clear` declaration is in the "one or two CSS rules", particularly those whose selector contains (or is) `.clearfloat`. That fixes the height of the box of the float having an otherwise *last* child element that is *not* a float. I should look like so:

```
.clearfloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

More elaborate and hackish workarounds are known, for example:

```
.clearfloat {
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But in some layout engines (particularly MSHTML < 8) the clearing element must have content. Yet we do not want that dummy element to be visible. Hence the (empty) *comment*.

Comment: I see quite a few blog posts about the font-size: 0 hack, but that seemed ridiculous to me.

Comment: I presume the idea behind this was/is “better safe than sorry”. `line-height: 0` by itself does not prevent possible content from being displayed. It turns out that in Chromium 33 `height: 0` by itself does nothing at all, not even with `display: block`. It is only either `font-size: 0` or `height: 0; overflow: hidden` that lets the content disappear; but the latter only works with `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty common. I wondered about this as well when I was younger. As far as I know, this is to signal to other programmers that the contents of the div were left intentionally empty, and this serves as a completely "blank" content in the div.

In other cases, it may be used to remove whitespace.